# Get array subset in mongodb using an array source

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this document's structure:

```
{
    Id: "id_value",
    Elements:[
                {
                    InnerId: "inner_id_value1",
                    Value: "apple"
                },
                {
                    InnerId: "inner_id_value2",
                    Value: "pear"
                },
                {
                    InnerId: "inner_id_value3",
                    Value: "banana"
                }
             ]
}
```

What i need to do is create a query which receives in input an array (for example `["apple","banana","coconut"]` ) and returns to me:

```
{
    Id: "id_value",
    Elements:[
                {
                    InnerId: "inner_id_value1",
                    Value: "apple"
                },
                {
                    InnerId: "inner_id_value3",
                    Value: "banana"
                }
             ]
}
```

Is it possible do it in Mongo with a single query?

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: @Styvane version 3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to `$filter` the array and keep only those subdocument where the *value* is a subset of your input array. Note that *value* here is one element array where element is the embedded field `value`.

```
let fruits = ["apple","banana","coconut"];

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "Element": { 
            "$filter": { 
                "input": "$Element", 
                "as": "el", 
                "cond": { 
                    "$setIsSubset": [ [ "$$el.Value" ], fruits ] 
                 }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

---

Starting from MongoDB 3.4* you can use the `$in` operator in the `$project` stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "Element": { 
            "$filter": { 
                "input": "$Element", 
                "as": "el", 
                "cond": { 
                    "$in": [ "$$el.Value", fruits ] 
                 }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

<sub>*Unreleased version of MongoDB as the time of this writing</sub>

Comment: $setIsSubset is new to me. Thanks!
Just curious about the null set scenario, since it is a subset of every set - if $$el.Value is empty for a document, wont that also be included in this query result?

Comment: No it will not be included.