# Getting the existing items on a sub list in a specific document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm new into mongodb, and I've got stuck with getting a projection right...

This is my document:

```
{  
   "field1":"value1",
   "field2":[  
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3",
      "item4"
   ]
}
```

and this is some wanted list :

```
["item1", "item3","item5"];
```

and I'd like to get the existing items in field 2, from the above "wanted list".
in my example the result value should be ["item1","item2"]

what is the projection for that?
This one doesn't work:

```
db.users.find({"field1": "value1"}, {"field1" : 1,"field2": {$in: ["item1", "item3","item5"]}}).pretty()
```

Thanks a lot!

Solved:
Thanks to Anthony Winzlet, all that was missing is that it has to match field 1 like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {"field1": "value1"}
  },
  { "$project": {
    "field2": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$field2",
        "cond": {
          "$in": [
            "$$this",
            ["item1", "item3", "item5"]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: I think you want [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) or [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/)

Comment: Or even better [Get array subset in mongodb using an array source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774492/get-array-subset-in-mongodb-using-an-array-source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "field2": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$field2",
        "cond": {
          "$in": [
            "$$this",
            ["item1", "item3", "item5"]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```