# Extract a slice of a tab in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, slice

I would like to extract only a slice from a tab stored in MongoDB.
The limit of the slice are contained into the same document.

Example, here I would like to extract `myTab[iStart:iEnd]`, returning `[2,3,4,5]`

```
post = {'myTab':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'iStart':1,
        'iEnd':4}
```

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      myTab: {
        $slice: [
          "$myTab",
          1,
          4
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])` ? or `db.collection.find({},
{
  myTab: {
    $slice: [
      1,
      4
    ]
  }
})`

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the limit of the slice to come from the document variable value. So something like that, but it does not seem to work...: `db.collection.find({}, { myTab: { $slice: [ this.iStart, this.iEnd ] } })`

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      myTab: {
        $slice: [
          "$myTab",
          "$iStart",
          "$iEnd"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])` Use `$` to access document fields

Comment: Thanks, reading the documentation, the exact answer would be : `db.collection.aggregate([ { $project: { myTab: { $slice: [ "$myTab", "$iStart", {$subtract:["$iEnd","$iStart"] } ] } } } ])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get array subset in mongodb using an array source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774492/get-array-subset-in-mongodb-using-an-array-source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$slice`

```
{ $slice: [ <array>, <position>, <n> ] }
```

Reference link : [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)